# React - Browser doesn't detect changes and console says '[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I am pretty new to React, sorry if I am asking something stupid. Any help would be highly appreciated :)

**ENVIRONMENT**

- Ubuntu 20.04 in Windows 10 (WSL2)
- Node version - v14.1.0
- Npm version - v6.14.7
- Code editor - VS Code v1.14.0

**STEPS I DID**

1. `npx create-react-app <app-name>`
2. `cd <app-name>`
3. `npm start`
4. `https://localhost:3000` opens up in browser with default React landing page. Console says '[HMR] Waiting for update signal from WDS...
   '
5. Delete all files in `src` directory and create empty `index.js` in `src` directory.

Output expected: Blank screen

Output: Default landing page of React even if I reload the page.

### Struggles I made before asking this question :(

- Looked in issues of `create-react-app`.
- Tried troubleshooting `create-react-app` as mentioned in official docs.
- Looked in stackoverflow for similar questions. Found some but none worked, maybe because my dev environment was different from them (WSL2 in Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

That sounds like a caching issue to me. My guess would be to clear your google chrome cache and try again. If that doesn't work, check your package.json file and make sure that under "scripts": "start" it says "react-scripts start".

Comment: Thats honestly something I haven't seen before. Try running this command `sudo apt update && sudo apt -y upgrade && sudo apt autoremove` in your WSL terminal?

Answer (score 0):

Yayy! The issue is resolved.
It was my mistake :(.
All these days, I was trying to access the Windows filesystem from WSL2 and it seemed to be very slow. So I decided to work in the Linux filesystem itself. And everything works fine now. Thanks for helping :)